# Mapping and Texturing Separate Sections?

Tags: texturing, uv

[image: This is the apple model with it's stem.]
I've begun texturing a model I've been working on but have run into some trouble. I need to texture the stem differently from the rest of the apple but have no idea how to do that and couldn't find anything saying how. How would I be able to do this? (Map and Texture the stem separate from the apple eve thought they're the same object)

Comment: possible duplicate: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Comment: it depends if you want to use an Image Texture or not. If you want to, you'll have to unwrap your mesh. Otherwise you'll just have to assign the material you want on the part of the mesh you want.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that. Yes I am using an image mesh. How would I go about unwrapping the sections?